# php max function returns min value from array

Tags: php, file, max

this is my first post. sorry if i did something wrong...

anyways i have a file that gets updates by php and this is EXACTLY it:

```
31\n
127\n
131\n
124\n
144\n
142\n
133\n
133\n
9\n
0\n
22\n
18\n
```

i made this script in php:

```
$logContents = file_get_contents("logs/mainlog.txt");
$logitemArray = explode("\n", $logContents);

echo max($logitemArray);
```

but it echos 9. why? it said in the php documentation that max() should return the biggest value in the array

thanks in advance

Comment: `9` is the largest when sorted lexicographically, which means you're using strings, not numbers. You need to turn them into numbers first to get the max numerical value

Comment: I think because they are treated as strings, not as ints. Then 9 is the greatest

Comment: Form the manual: `Caution 
Be careful when passing arguments with mixed types values because max() can produce unpredictable results`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explode()` returns an array of strings, so they're being compared lexicographically. You need to convert them to numbers so that `max()` will compare them numerically.

```
$logitemArray = array_map('intval', explode("\n", $logContents));
echo max($logitemArray);
```

BTW, you can use the `file()` function to read a file directly into an array of lines, instead of using `file_get_contents()` followed by `explode()`.

```
$logitemArray = array_map('intval', file("logs/mainlog.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
```

Comment: thank you the secound method is way more simpler and im guessing faster than get_contents and explode also array_map fixed the problem thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments have said, it's because 9 is the largest lexigraphical value. If it said 900 it would still be the same.

This is because when you split the string with `explode` you get an array of type string. The following code will convert the elements in the array to integers  which should give expected behaviour.

```
$logitemArray = array_map('intval', explode("\n", $logContents));
```